# Confused about WinMain Example return type

Tags: c++, winapi

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

In the example shown it looks like the WinMain function has two return types?: "int" & "WINAPI"?

I'm not familiar with the syntax of what's going on here.  Is "WINAPI" a return type or something else?

Comment: A yes that answers my question, sorry I did some searches, but did't come across that.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out it was a calling convention more information can be found at the link that Benjamin Lindley posted here: [what does WINAPI stand for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463346/what-does-winapi-stand-for)

Answer (score -1):

WINAPI is not the return type, it's some microsoft bullshit.

*wap*

Excuse me, I meant to say that WINAPI is macro that actually evaluates to __stdcall.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348442/winapi-main-function) is a question that is very similar to yours, with more details. Basically, these are compiler extensions. I believe gcc provides similar extensions via the [**attributes**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) keyword.