# Which return type? (C++ | Win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, definition, return-type

I have a simple question.
What does "WINAPI" mean in following definition:

```
int WINAPI WinMain ();
```

I think, that the **return type** is int and the function **name** is WinMain, but I can't figure out, what "WINAPI" means in this case.

Thanks :)

Comment: It's definition can be found in one of the compiler's header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a macro that is used to specify the calling convention of the function.

The [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) defines it as:

```
#define WINAPI __stdcall
```

The meaning of `__stdcall` is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381406(v=vs.85).aspx

> WINAPI is the calling convention. A calling convention defines how a function receives parameters from the caller. For example, it defines the order that parameters appear on the stack.

Comment: `WINAPI` is a macro that specifies the calling convention (`__stdcall`).  It isn't a calling convention of its own.

Comment: Bad Microsoft.  No biscuit.

Answer (score 1):

It is also already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463346/what-does-winapi-stand-for).

> Typical c calls are compiled using what's known as cdecl. In cdecl the
>   caller cleans up the arguments pushed on the stack.
>
> WINAPI, also known as "standard call" means that the called function
>   is responsible for cleaning up the stack of its arguments.
>
> The MS compiler will prefix a cdecl call with a _, while a WINAPI gets
>   a leading _ and gets an @{BYTES-NEEDED} prepended to the function name
>   when it mangles the function names.