# explanation of this complex typedef

Tags: c++, winapi

so what does this typedef syntax actually do?

```
typedef PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS (WINAPI *CHECKSUMMAPPEDFILE)
          (PVOID baseAddress, DWORD fileLength, PDWORD headerSum, PDWORD checkSum);
```

from what I know typedef is used like this typedef oldtype newtype;
but overhere the whole thing looks like a prototype of a function, but it also looks like it is creating a new type of PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS...

as somebody responded "function typedefs" but an example of a function typedef can bye this

```
typedef int multiply(int arg1, int arg2);
```

where multiply is the function name, but in the complex one I posted above, where is the function name?

Comment: function typedef.

Comment: It's a function pointer. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer) for more details.

Comment: ok going to read that now @Nikita

Comment: I've just edited your question to put a linebreak in the declaration, so we can see it without needing to scroll.  Feel free to revert if you don't like it.

Comment: A somewhat useful rule of thumb: look for the verb.

Answer (score 2):

Your `typedef` creates an alias `CHECKSUMMAPPEDFILE`. `CHECKSUMMAPPEDFILE` is a pointer to a function that returns an `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS` and takes as arguments `PVOID baseAddress, DWORD fileLength, PDWORD headerSum, PDWORD checkSum`. From the first look syntax of such a `typedef` is not obvious.

and `WINAPI` is [calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463346/what-does-winapi-stand-for).

Comment: ... and uses the `WINAPI` calling convention.

Comment: @IInspectable Missed it, thnx!

Answer (score 1):

This is a type alias for a function pointer. You can use it to define a variable to which you can assign a function.

This:

```
typedef int multiply(int arg1, int arg2);
```

is a typedef for a function type, you cannot use it the same way as function pointer. See example below:

```
int mul(int arg1, int arg2) {
}

typedef int multiply(int arg1, int arg2);
int main() {
    //multiply m = mul; // error multiply is a typedef for a funciton type
    multiply* m = mul; // ok
}
```

---

What your type alias :

```
typedef PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS (WINAPI *CHECKSUMMAPPEDFILE)(PVOID baseAddress,   
                               DWORD fileLength, PDWORD headerSum, PDWORD checkSum);
```

do:

> it declares a CHECKSUMMAPPEDFILE as pointer to function (PVOID, DWORD, PDWORD, PDWORD) with WINAPI calling convention returning PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS

You might use [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) to decifer function pointers, it offen requires some tweaking to make it work.